# Angular reactive form data conversion

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have data coming from server that are formatted in meters but in the interface I need to display and edit in inches then send it back to server again in meters.
There is some technique to handle the conversion dynamically, say using a converter function bound to formControl or whatever?
I'm using angular material components.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The short answer is yes there are a lot of "techniques" to handle that conversion dynamically. We'd be way more useful if you show us how you're trying to do that so we can guide you.

Comment: Hi!
You could use ngModel which creates a FormControl instance from a domain model and binds it to a form control element. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwrn2j?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I don't have an example tho show, but in short I use patchValue() to apply data than the value property to get data to send back to server

Comment: @salgaf Can you not create an example in stackblitz?

Comment: For me, who must mannage the conversion is the service. Use `pipe(map(x=>...))` after the httClient.get the value/s and before send the data make the proper conversion. This allow your component works on inches

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way is to actually make use of a directive to do your conversion to inches so that you don't have to worry about the server data.

something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="newForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <input formatData formControlName="data"/>
</form>

onSubmit() {
// ...conversion back to meters
}
```

I am using reactive forms as that is more dynamic and something that I use a lot as I build my forms dynamically but you can also do the same with template forms.

Comment: I'm also using reactive forms , have you an example to follow?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Angular Pipes** to transform the data and then display them in your Interface (view).

Pipes are angular decorated class that implements a transform function which takes in data as input and transforms it to a desired output and show them to users (as they can be added to your HTML). You can read more about them [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), and write a Custom Pipe for your purpose.

Comment: Pipes is usable in two ways? I mean convert for the interface and convert back for the data to send?

Comment: No they will only convert data to display for interface, to convert the data back create a reverse function and call it while submitting the form.